# Cassandra SASI index with multiple fields

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

Cassandra SASI indexes allow queries similar to SQL LIKE on a single field. I was wondering if it is possible to perform LIKE queries on multiple fields:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE 'joh%'
AND LASTNAME LIKE 'smi%'
```

Is this possible using SASI indexes or something else in Cassandra ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible but only by using ALLOW FILTERING.

As per the DataStax docs - "If ALLOW FILTERING is used, SASI also supports queries with multiple predicates using AND. With SASI, the performance pitfalls of using filtering are not realized because the filtering is not performed even if ALLOW FILTERING is used" - https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/cql/cql/cql_using/useSASIIndexConcept.html

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE 'joh%' AND LASTNAME LIKE 'smi%' allow filtering;
```

But this is just a syntax rule and it should not cause a performance hit when you have SASI index on both the columns.

You can read a lot about SASI implementation here : http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=2058